# Error when implementing overloading operator "+"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a `MyClass` which is a linked list for which I have overidden the operator+:

```
MyNode
{
   int value;
   MyNode* link;
}
```

```
MyClass
{
   MyNode* first;
   MyNode* current;
   MyNode* last;
   int count;
}
```

```
MyClass MyClass::operator+(MyClass* operand)
{
   MyClass sum;
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      MyNode* newNode
      newNode->value = value + operand->value;
      sum->insert(newNode);
   }
   return sum;   
}
```

When I try to implement this in my main function like so:

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass();
MyClass* b = new MyClass();
MyClass* c;

c = a + b;
```

The compiler throws an error: "cannot add two pointers".

Comment: The way you've written it, you'd need the left side to be a normal object, as well as `c`. I'm not sure why you're using `new` at all. This is C++.

Comment: It might improve our ability to communicate the solution to you if you would post an actual program, and not pseudo-code. Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you coming from a Java background?  You don't need `new` to create objects:

Try this:

```
MyClass MyClass::operator+(const MyClass& operand)
{
   MyClass result;

   // Perform addition ...

   return result;  
}

MyClass a;
MyClass b;
MyClass c;

c = a + b;
```

Comment: I guessed that and looked at the tags. It seems Java it is.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't use pointers. My code has been updated.

Comment: For clarification, `MyClass` is a linked list and I am overriding the operator+ so that I can add two linked list with a simple expression.

Comment: To be clear: the problem is that you have declared `a`, `b`, and `c` as pointers. Your updated code STILL declares them as pointers. Declare them as objects instead, and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. First, your operator has a wrong signature. `operator+` should take a const reference as an argument and return a const value. Thus:

```
const MyClass MyClass::operator+(const MyClass& operand)
```

Second, you're trying to add the pointers themselves rather than the objects they point to. So you need:

```
*c = *a + *b;
```

And to be 100% correct, the operator itself should be declared as a `const` function:

```
 const MyClass MyClass::operator+(const MyClass& operand) const
```